# Replace duplicated values with blank in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on Pandas data frame.
The example code will be as follow:
`
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
                  {'name1': ['A', 'C', 'A', 'B','C', 'D','D', 'C', 'A', 'B','C', 'A'], 
                   'name2': ['B', 'D', 'C', 'D','B','A','A', 'D', 'C', 'D','D','B'], 
                   'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                   'Value1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5], 
                   'Value2': [0, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                  },
                  columns=['name1','name2','id','Value1','Value2'])`
```

I can do the agg using the following groupby:

```
m = df.groupby(['id','name1',])['Value1'].sum()
```

When I printed **m**, it will show as follow:

```
   id  name1
    1   A        4
        B        4
        C        7
        D        6
    2   A        9
        B        6
        C        5
        D        0
    Name: Value1, dtype: int64
```

When I wrote **m** it to csv file, it will only contain the value1 as it is a pandas series.
Using this series, I want to create a dataframe that is exactly the same as the **table below**

```
  id name1  Value1
  1     A      4
  1     B      4
  1     C      7
  1     D      6
  2     A      9
  2     B      6
  2     C      5
  2     D      0
```

Anyone advise me how to do that?
Thanks a lot
Zep

Comment: write into excel

Comment: Thanks Wen, I will write it to excel now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to save to CSV, here's a hack you can use to fix the display before saving.

```
m = m.sort_index().reset_index()
m['id'] = m['id'].mask(m['id'].ne(m['id'].shift()).cumsum().duplicated(), '')

print(m)
  id name1  Value1
0  1     A       4
1        B       4
2        C       7
3        D       6
4  2     A       9
5        B       6
6        C       5
7        D       0

m.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Disclaimer; if you're doing anything besides saving, do *not* run this beforehand.

Comment: Thanks ColdSpeed. If i would like to set id for all blank id row with same id, how can i do that?
it means, my final table will look the last table in the post.

Comment: @Zephyr *coldspeed 

Comment: @Zephyr save this: `m.sort_index().reset_index().to_csv(...)`

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed
How can i directly convert this series to dataframe as shown in the table in the post?
thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: Thanks. I mean without saving it to CSV. Just to convert to dataframe. Should I just remove the .to_csv part?

Comment: @Zephyr yes that would be enough. You can just do `m = m.reset_index()` or `m = m.to_frame()`

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed.

Answer (score 3):

simply,

```
 #reseting the index
 m = m.sort_index().reset_index()
 #masking duplicated value with empty
 m['id']=m['id'].mask(m['id'].duplicated(),"")
 #writing dataframe to a csv file
 m.to_csv("output.csv",index=False)
```